# Gitlab backup without repository commits

Tags: git, backup, gitlab

I have a gitlab instance running; some repositories are over 400MB, and I don't want those to be backed up. I want to back up all gitlab configs, users keys, and projects with issues.

In other words what I want to do is keep backups and when I restore a backup get everything except repository files, so users will simply push their repositories to server and everything will be restored.

If I back up `/var/opt/gitlab`, will it give me the result i am expecting?

Comment: although you could do what you propose, it is likely that the gitlab users will end up loosing data. It is not uncommon for someone to have a local git clone that is filled with failed attempts, branches that have are merged incorrectly, etc. It happens just because local git clones are not expected to be used by anyone else.

Comment: It is for internal use in organisation, not for public. How can i achieve same ? , Can i exclude few repository & backup gitlab ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a current version of GitLab you can do the following to skip repositories when creating a backup:

Install from source:

```
$ sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:backup:create SKIP=repositories RAILS_ENV=production
```

Omnibus:

```
$ sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create SKIP=repositories
```

http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/raketasks/backup_restore.html

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to fetch the latest commit of each branch without the full history.

**`git clone <url> --branch <branch_name> --depth <#of commits to fetch>`**

`--depth=1` This will checkout only the latest commit of the required branch.
You can work on it and pull/push it back again.

Comment: I am talking about gitlab backup.